# My Jquery.ajax method is getting an error status in response despite the successful transfer of json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, twitter-bootstrap

This is my jquery method :

```
<script>
    function onNotify() {
        console.log(jQuery('form #Name').val());
        var deviceInfo = platform;
        var for_name = jQuery('form #Name').val();
        console.log(for_name);
        var for_email = jQuery('form #Email').val();
        var for_phone = jQuery('form #phone').val();
        var for_checkindate = jQuery('form #date-picker-2').val();

        var for_checkoutdate = jQuery('form #date-picker-out').val();
        console.log(for_checkindate);
        console.log(for_checkoutdate);
        var appointment = {
            "inquirer": for_name,
            "email": for_email,
            "phone": for_phone,
            "checkoutDate": for_checkoutdate,
            "checkinDate": for_checkindate,

        };
        console.log(appointment);
        var hostname = document.URL.concat("bookings");
        console.log(hostname);
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: document.URL.concat("bookings"),
            crossDomain: true,
            data: appointment,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                setTimeout(90000);
                console.log("response with:", response);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log("ERROR:", error);
            },
            complete: function () {
                jQuery('#Message-success-label').show();
                jQuery('#Message-success-label').fadeOut(8000);
                jQuery('form #Name').val('');
                jQuery('form #Email').val('');
                jQuery('form #phone').val('');
                jQuery('form #date-picker-2').val('');
                jQuery('form #date-picker-out').val('');
                console.log("done");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

And this the form calling the method :

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">

        <div class="slideform form-group">
            <label style="font-family:'Source Sans Pro';font-weight:400" for="Name">Name</label>
            <input type="name" class="form-control" id="Name" placeholder="Name" name="your-name" required="">
        </div>
        <div class="slideform form-group">
            <label style="font-family:'Source Sans Pro';font-weight:400" for="phone">Phone Number</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" name="your-phone" required="">
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="slideform form-group">
            <label style="font-family:'Source Sans Pro';font-weight:400" for="Email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email" placeholder="Email" name="your-email" required="">
        </div>
        <div class="slideform checkin form-group date-form form-horizontal">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label style="font-family:'Source Sans Pro';font-weight:400" for="date-picker-2" class="control-label">Check In</label>
                <div class="input-group controls">
                    <input id="date-picker-2" type="text" class="date-picker form-control" placeholder="Check In" name="your-checkindate" required="">
                    <label for="date-picker-2" class="input-group-addon btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="slideform checkout form-group date-form form-horizontal">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label style="font-family:'Source Sans Pro';font-weight:400" for="date-picker-2" class="control-label">Check Out</label>
                <div class="input-group controls">
                    <input id="date-picker-out" type="text" class="date-picker form-control" placeholder="Check Out" name="your-checkoutdate" required="">
                    <label for="date-picker-out" class="input-group-addon btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <input type="submit" onclick="onNotify()" class="btn btn-default" value="Book a stay">
        </button>
        <p><span style="color:red;display:none" id="messagebook-success"><label id="Message-success-label" class="success-message">Thank you. We have received your request and shall revert shortly.</label></span>
        </p>
    </form>
```

While my code manages to send the json across to server via post successfully of this format :

```
{ inquirer: 'Jon',
  email: 'jogn@example.com',
  phone: '34659124',
  checkoutDate: '12/18/2014',
  checkinDate: '12/03/2014' }
```

I am recieving an error status it seems because, I am getting the following  error in my browser console :

```
ERROR: 
Object {readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
```

Also on click of the submit button a get request is sent across apparently as url changes to :

```
http://localhost:9001/?your-name=Jon&your-phone=34659124&your-email=jon%40example.com&your-checkindate=12%2F03%2F2014&your-checkoutdate=12%2F18%2F2014
```

and the whole page reloads despite it being an ajax call? I am at my wits end with this problem nothing seems to make sense please guide..

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. see http://json.org/

Comment: Can u please elaborate so that I can fix and problem and then study more about json.. I am actually new to the study of json.

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes in your JSON.
Also, if you don't want the form to be actually submitted, hook the form submit event and use event.preventDefault() rather than calling the function in onclick attribute.

```
$( "#myForm" ).submit( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    onNotify();
});
```

Or update your function:

```
function onNotify(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // your function body here
}
```

And use:

```
$( "#myForm" ).submit( onNotify );
```

Comment: I am using double quotes right? -
 var appointment = {
            "inquirer": for_name,
            "email": for_email,
            "phone": for_phone,
            "checkoutDate": for_checkoutdate,
            "checkinDate": for_checkindate,

        };

Comment: Just make your appointment an array and call var jsonString = JSON.stringify(appointment);